# Iframe will not display image

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I use a hidden iframe to post a photo the user selects from their local disk.  I'm then trying to display that image on a div on the same page as the hidden iframe.  It is not displaying the image in the div and I've spent hours mucking with it.

HERE IS THE HTML:

```
<iframe name="upload_iframe" id="upload_iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>

<form name="pictureForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <span>Upload Picture</span>
        <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" 
                 onchange="return FileUpload(this);" />

        <!-- this div is where I need the uploaded image to show....-->
        <div id="picture_preview"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When the user selects an image file, you can see above that my `onchange` calls `FileUpload(this)` -- here is FileUpload(), a javascript function:

```
function FileUpload(the_upload_field)
{  
    // show a 'progress bar' image whilst we do the image file upload
    //  -- this works fine.
    document.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML 
          = '<div><img src="images/progressbar.gif" border="0" /></div>';

    // now post the image to the server using the hidden iframe
    the_upload_field.form.action = 'photoPreview.php';
    the_upload_field.form.target = 'upload_iframe';
    the_upload_field.form.submit();
    the_upload_field.form.action = '';
    the_upload_field.form.target = '';

    return true;
}
```

You see that I'm posting this hidden iframe to photoPreview.php -- here is that code:

```
$upload_dir = 'file-upload/upload/';     // Directory for file storing
$preview_url = 'http://localhost/myWebsite/file-upload/upload/';


// NOTE:  the 'picture' here is the name of the open-file html element above
$filename = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
$targetDirForFile = $upload_dir .  $filename;

// extract the uploaded file and put it into the web server upload folder...
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $targetDirForFile);

// EDIT: this was in my code but forgot to include it here, now done so.
$fullImagePath = $preview_url . $filename; 

// This is PHP code outputing Javascript code.
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'."\n";

//echo 'var parDoc = window.parent.document;';  // didn't work either.
echo 'var parDoc = parent.document;';

// if you look in the html code above, you see that 'picture_preview' 
// used here is a div, and that's where I need the image to appear
$outStr = "parDoc.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML = '<div><img src=\'$fullImagePath\' /></div>';";

// display the image to the 'picture_preview' div on the same page as the
// hidden iframe...

// EDIT: THIS WAS THE SOURCE OF MY PROBLEM.  This showAlertBox() is my homemade
// helper function that displays PHP variables to the browser when I'm debugging.
// If you look at my code below for 'showAlertBox()' you see that it prematurely
// was ending the 'javascript' section of the code due to its own final '/script'
// WHEN I COMMENT OUT this call to showAlertBox(), my image now successfully appears.
showAlertBox("the outStr is" . $outStr);


echo $outStr;
echo "\n".'</script>';
exit();
```

I see the progressbar.gif in the picture_preview div but not the uploaded image.

This should work, probably something simple I'm not seeing, I've been at this for 10 hours trying everything.

Also, moving the iframe inside the form above made no difference at all.

EDIT:  I FIXED THIS PROBLEM.  Here was the cause of my problem, my showAlertBox() helper function, which spits out PHP variables to the browser when I'm debugging my PHP code, and it has a trailing /script that prevented my final line of code, 'echo outStr', from executing and displaying the image:

```
 function showAlertBox($messageToDisplay)
 {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
         . 'alert("' . $messageToDisplay . '")</script>';
 }
```

Comment: This won't work. Your form is getting submitted means the page is getting refreshed. You'll have to do the form submission maybe using ajax and get the progress from server to show the progress bar.

Comment: @mohkhan OP is submitting the form to an iframe, which would not cause the top window to reload. to OP: Do you see any error on your browser console?

Comment: @Passerby, let me check.

Comment: it says [00:22:21.156] Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost/theSite/postAd.php
[00:22:21.156] Error in parsing value for 'height'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost/theSite/postAd.php  [00:22:21.156] Error in parsing value for 'clip'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost/theSite/postAd.php   EDIT: this is totally unrelated, coming from a different html syntax error I just found.

Comment: Check the content of your `iframe`, do you see the expected script content (including a correct image path)? Because I don't see you setting `$fullImagePath` in your posted code.

Comment: It was in my code, forgot to copy it to my question, have updated the code above.  I see in the iframe this:  parDoc.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML = '  and then a 'broken link' tiny icon.  (Note that for debugging I make the iframe visible with display=block.)

Comment: Have you given out the proper headers and content type in your iframe? The content type should be `text/html`, and the iframe should not show the JS code.

Comment: No, the code PHP code above that outputs the javascript to the iframe is the extent of what I have so far.

Comment: @CFHcoder If you want to use JS in your iframe, the content of the iframe should be a completed HTML with proper HTML content type, otherwise browsers will just treat your code as text and directly _display_ them.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not sure what that entails, not sure what the code is for that.  Do you mean the 'DOCTYPE html' statement?

Comment: @CFHcoder `<?php header("Content-Type: text/html");?><html><head></head><body><script>...</script></body></html>`

Comment: I FIXED IT.  I had an extra 'script' that prematurely was closing the javascript code before my final 'echo outStr' statement.  It doesn't appear in my code because I use a 'helper' function called showAlertBox() in all my PHP development to display the values of php variables in the browser window -- my showAlertBox() uses javascript with a beginning 'script', an 'alert( somePHPvariable )' then a closing 'script' -- and that 'shut off' my final  'echo outStr' line of code that was supposed to show the image.  I got rid of my showAlertBox() call and voila it works.

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED IT. I had an extra 'script' tag that prematurely was closing the javascript code before my final 'echo outStr' statement. It doesn't appear in my code because it comes from a 'helper' function I use called showAlertBox() in all my PHP development to display the values of php variables in the browser window -- my showAlertBox() uses javascript with a beginning 'script', an 'alert( somePHPvariable )' then a closing 'script' -- and that 'shut off' my final 'echo outStr' line of code that was supposed to show the image. I got rid of my showAlertBox() call and voila it works